# The best Way to implement ReactJS in Django App

Tags: django, reactjs, templates

I have worked in Django for sometime and i am trying to learn ReactJS. I was wondering what is the best way to use ReactJS with Django.

1. Having ReactJS within the Django Project to act as a template system.
2. Having ReactJS as a separate front-end app and interact with Django through a REST API.

What is your experience in either of those 2 methods ?

Comment: I would say it depends on what kind of application you are creating. PS: you could also mix both techniques. Let django render different pages, and then add frontend functionality through additional REST urls

Answer (score 2):

React is capable to being a stand alone static website with Django being the rest api endpoint, but this process would involve advanced concepts of ReactJs like react router and extra effort in managing security via session variables.

On the other hand you could have each module as a stand alone React App which is directly being rendered from Django itself, over here the drawback is that the performance will be slower mainly due to page refresh as and when required, but this to is one of the correct ways to use react within Django and not as a separate standalone application

In your case, since ReactJs is new to you, i suggest you go for ReactJs templated within the Django app